# Escaping data for use within a CodeIgniter View

Tags: security, codeigniter, escaping

I have a controller and a view; the data that I'm working with inside the controller can't be trusted (it's drawn from somewhere external, and isn't `$_GET` or `$_POST`).

How do I escape the data when printing it in the view to ensure that tags and other things are escaped properly? I'm used to Zend_View's `$this->escape($foo)`, which is used from inside the view, so I'm still trying to get my bearings. My preference is to escape it from within the view, as I use the data, but if that's not an option I'll do it within the controller.

(I've discovered the filtering for $this->input, but as the data isn't coming from `$_GET`/`$_POST` it's not much use to me. :-) Unfortunately, the examples I've seen so far have all been using a controller putting static data into an array, which is then passing to the view, eg. `$data['foo'] = 'Example'`)

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I'm asking because I don't particularly relish using [`html_entities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')`](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070327/htmlspecialchars-strikes-again/#comment-25954) everywhere (along with `mb_convert_encoding()` and friends), but I guess I'll create a custom helper if needed.

**Edit #2:** The data is a bunch of strings (that may contain anything from straight alphanumeric characters, to `<b>foo</b>`, to `<script>alert('xsslol');</script>`.

I need to escape these strings to print them within, say, table cells, not allowing any HTML tags to be printed (converting tags into their HTML entity equivalents).
If I were working with bare PHP, I'd use htmlentities() for this, as per my edit above.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the nature of the data you're getting and how it should display, it's sort of hard to answer this.

You can still use the input class xss_clean method anywhere, since the default is to have it initialized. You could do this in the controller before you send it to the view or in the view:

```
echo $this->input->xss_clean($mystery_data);
```

Note: xss_clean is **not** running automatically on POST and COOKIE data unless you've set this in your apps config file:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

You can take a look at it in system/libraries/Input.php, it's pretty thorough.

Comment: My apologies, I should've been more specific. Please see the second edit above.  
(xss_clean() by itself doesn't do the escaping I need.)

Comment: In that case then I would probably make a helper like you said in the first edit.